# can i use Spring parameterized class used instead of spring autowire

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, inversion-of-control, spring-bean

I have a class say

```
public class Test {     
    String x ;      
    public Test(String xyz) {
        this.x = xyz;
    }       
    public void print() {
        System.out.println(this.x);
    }    
}
```

I want to use this in spring bean like :

```
@service 
class TestService implements Service{

@Autowired
Repo repo;

Test t = null;

public void m1(String z){

   t = new Test(z);
....
.....
}
```

}
Is this right approach?since i have it parameterized and i want to provide the parameter in the method. i know that spring default scope is singleton so if i deploy it on web will there be any issues?

or i should just do :
Test t = new Test(z);

Comment: _Normally_ you should be supplying the `Test` object. (Also note that it is better to make `Repo` a constructor parameter and `final`; field injection has lots of problems.)

Comment: Repo is fine . my question is mostly about test . repo i can autowire as it is not a parameterized class.

Comment: Your phrase "parameterized class" is not standard, and I don't understand what you mean by it. Your use of names that are not meaningful (`Test`, `m1`, `z`) makes it difficult to understand your intention.

Comment: Test is a parameterized class, m1 is a method in spring service. z is a parameter .

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem to use Test class like a type or private field.
You don't need to initialize it as **null** to initialize this field you can use the @PostConstruct annotation

Just do like:

```
@Service 
class TestService{
    private Test test;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init(){
       this.test = new Test("123");
    }
}
```

And the in your methods you can change the value of this.test field